# Make "apt-get update" show the exact output as `apt update`

Tags: apt

I'm learning the CLI interface of Advanced Packaging Tool. From the output of `apt(8)` when its stdout isn't a terminal, it isn't suitable for "scripts expecting stable programming interface", so I'm taking a look at `apt-get(8)`.

One difference between `apt update` and `apt-get update` is that the latter is missing a final line after all cache has been updated:

```
8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

I want to know how I can get this exact line displayed with `apt-get(8)`.

Comment: As far as I knew, `apt` (Advanced Packaging Tool) and `apt-get` are different things. They're designed to run differently from what I understood. If one gives you what you want, perhaps make the habit to use that command instead.

Answer (score 9):

`man apt-get` shows:

```
   -s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
       No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur based on
       the current system state but do not actually change the system.
       Locking will be disabled (Debug::NoLocking) so the system state
       could change while apt-get is running. Simulations can also be
       executed by non-root users which might not have read access to all
       apt configuration distorting the simulation. A notice expressing
       this warning is also shown by default for non-root users
       (APT::Get::Show-User-Simulation-Note). Configuration Item:
       APT::Get::Simulate.
```

So if you just do:

`apt-get upgrade --dry-run`

it will output:

```
...
4 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I went through `man 8 apt-get` and found that option, but the output was different from `apt`.

Comment: Different how?  I just checked on my system and it's identical.  I thought it was identical because `apt` is really a programmatic wrapper around `apt-get` and that's the reason why the warning exists.

Comment: `apt` shows `8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.`, while your answer shows `4 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.`

Comment: Yes, that's because you have 8 to upgrade where I have 4.  Or are you referring to the text being different?

Comment: I'm talking about text being different, even after normalizing variables into `%d`. But +1 for a decent answer anyways.

Comment: note that when all packages are up to date `apt-get` wont display any message about available updates

Comment: Yes, that's *exactly* what the warning is about.  `apt` will not guarantee you that text, and they may not even guarantee you that number.  `apt-get` however has a strict output requirement because it's used by other softwares (like UIs and daemons) to process it in various ways.  So you can either change your code to accept `apt-get`'s output or you can `| sed 's/to upgrade/packages can be upgraded/g'`, for example (and risk your code breaking later).

Comment: Huh?  `$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.`

Comment: @tudor : mine dont output the summary... apt v1.6.10

Answer (score 4):

Guessing you need to handle the number of available updates, here is a suggestion:

```
# With no option, returns two numbers, no CR nor LF
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check

# With --human-readable, returns numbers, locale LANG text & CR/LF
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check  --human-readable
```

No need to sudo
The output is easy to work with

More options:

```
> /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check  --help
Usage: apt-check [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p, --package-names   Show the packages that are going to be
                        installed/upgraded
  --human-readable      Show human readable output on stdout
  --security-updates-unattended
                        Return the time in days when security updates are
                        installed unattended (0 means disabled)
```

Comment: Is this the exact thing used to generate `motd` on SSH login?

Comment: yes it looks like the same output, but i dunno how does motd

Answer (score 2):

From `man 8 apt`:

> ... enables some options ...

Then I went through `/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index.gz` (using `zcat(1)` to show text content) and noticed this option:

```
apt::cmd::show-update-stats
```

So I worked out the following command that did exactly what I wanted:

```
# apt-get -o apt::cmd::show-update-stats=true update
```

Tested to be working on Xenial and Bionic.